# How to configure a Many To Many relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have some articles and some authors, and want to link them as:

- any Article could have any amount of Authors and
- each Author can write any amount of Articles they want

I created a ManyToMany relationship using this Tutorial: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Here is how I defined my classes.

**Article**

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ArticleAuthor> ArticleAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

**Author**

```
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")] public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")] public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ArticleAuthor> ArticleAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

**ArticleAuthor**

```
public class ArticleAuthor
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    public Article Article { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ArticleAuthor> ArticleAuthors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleAuthor>()
            .HasKey(bc => new {bc.ArticleId, bc.AuthorId});
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleAuthor>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Article)
            .WithMany(b => b.ArticleAuthors)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ArticleId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleAuthor>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Author)
            .WithMany(c => c.ArticleAuthors)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.AuthorId);
    }
}
```

The Tables are created as expected after I ran *dotnet ef database update*

Everything seems well, except when I try to add an Article with an Author though this service:

**Service**

```
// POST: api/Articles
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostArticle([FromBody] Article article)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Articles.Add(article);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(article);
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "Title":"Title 2",
    "ReadingTime" : 2,
    "Date":"01.12.2019",
    "Theme": "1",
    "ArticleAuthors":[
        {
            "ID":"1"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to add an Article with an Author, I keep stucked with this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'AuthorId' on entity type 'ArticleAuthor' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

Comment: The EF configuration is ok. The JSON "ArticleAuthors" member is not. Looks like it's sending list of `Author` rather than list of `ArticleAuthor` ("ID"??)

Comment: @IvanStoev, thank you for the comment. Yeah indeed I am sending just Author id, not a ArticleAuthor. This is the way I do it using other ORM's such as Doctrine, Hibernate . Let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this payload, ArticleId and AuthorId should be required, ArticleId is implicit in the parent class, so you should provide at least AuthorId:

```
{
    "Title":"Title 2",
    "ReadingTime" : 2,
    "Date":"01.12.2019",
    "Theme": "1",
    "ArticleAuthors":[
        {
            "AuthorId":"1"
        }
    ]
}
```